# In Python, how do I read and write the actual word "None" (not the Keyword) between a .csv file and DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, keyword

I have a .csv that has the actual word "None" as a value in a field. When I read it into a DataFrame, the df reads "None" as the keyword and inserts . Later, when I rewrite the df to the .csv, all of the places where "None" was are replaced with blanks (`,,`) in the .csv.

testdata.csv:

```
Membership number,Last name,Date of birth,Status,Color
240200,,Wilson,None,Red
```

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "testdata.csv"
data_file = "testoutput.csv"

with open(filename, 'r', newline='', ):
    # Read data into a DataFrame
    user_df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    
user_df.to_csv(data_file, index=False)
```

testoutput.csv:

```
Membership number,Last name,Date of birth,Status,Color
240200,,Wilson,,Red
```

I want testoutput.csv to be the same as the testdata.csv.

Comment: I presume you're using Pandas. If so, you should state that explicitly and add a [tag:pandas] tag. It would also be helpful to include a [mre] in your question.

Comment: The extra line in your written csv is that the first line of a csv file is the headers.

Comment: `with open(filename, 'r', newline='', ):
    # Read data into a DataFrame
    user_df = pd.read_csv(filename)` What are you doing here? Why bother opening the file if your not going to use it?

Comment: @user3334278, you can use `pd.read_csv(filename, keep_default_na=False)`.

Comment: @TheTridentGuy Does one not need to open a file in order to read it?

Comment: @user3334278  `with open(filename, 'r', newline='', ):` opens the file, but doesn't assign it to anything. `with open(filename, 'r', newline='', ) as f:` would open it, and assign it to the variable `f`. You don't need to open the file because `read_csv()` opens the file internally.

Comment: I cannot duplicate this issue.  If I use THAT data file, and `read_csv` and `to_csv`, the output file is EXACTLY the same as the input file.  It would be a serious bug in pandas if the string "None" were transformed into NaNs.  Are you manipulating the dataframe after reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the extraneous file open, and as I expected, I cannot duplicate the issue.  Here is a session demonstrating that the output equals the input.

Source:

```
import pandas as pd

user_df = pd.read_csv('x.csv')
print(user_df)    
user_df.to_csv('x1.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ cat x.csv
Membership number,Last name,Date of birth,Status,Color
240200,,Wilson,None,Red
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ python x.py
   Membership number  Last name Date of birth Status Color
0             240200        NaN        Wilson   None   Red
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ cat x1.csv
Membership number,Last name,Date of birth,Status,Color
240200,,Wilson,None,Red
```

### Followup

This appears to be version-related.  The `read_csv` function does include a `na_values` parameter that identifies the list of strings that should be interpreted as NaN, and (at least in 2.0) "None" is on that list.

So, the two solutions are: specify a shorter list to `na_values`, or set `keep_default_na=False` to stop all NaN interpretation.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, only chnaging the filenames and got:
```
Membership number,Last name,Date of birth,Status,Color
240200,,Wilson,,Red
```

As @Timeless suggested, adding `keep_default_na=False` to your code gave me the desired effect.

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using because here with Pandas 2.0.1 I get the same output as the OP. In other words `'None' --> NaN --> Wilson,,Red`. Uisng `keep_default_na=False` in the `read_csv` prevents that.

Comment: Interesting.  The `read_csv` documentation shows there is an `na_values` parameters that tells what strings should be interpreted as NaN, and "None" is in the list.  My pandas is still 1.5.3, so it may be a version thing.  I'm willing to delete the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Well from here [NA Values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/user_guide/io.html#io-navaluesconst) I don't see `'None'` as one of the defaults for 1.5.2(the latest 1.5 version I could find).  So yes a version issue.